# firebird.FBManager not found

Tags: java, firebird, jaybird

I cannot find out how to get `org.firebirdsql.management.FBManager` to work.

I use Jaybird driver 2.2.2, the message I get is:

> package org.firebirdsql.management does not exist

I can connect to an existing DB, but when I try to use FBManager I'm stuck with this error.

Comment: The error message is a bit curious, as `FBManager` is a class, not a package. Include some code (specifically it looks like you have `import org.firebirdsql.management.FBManager.*` in your code, instead of `import org.firebirdsql.management.FBManager`)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I copied wrongly the error message sorry. The correct error is "package org.firebirdsql.management does not exist". Sorry for the mistake. I am using jaybird.

Comment: Please include the code, or describe exactly what you are doing (if you are using it as a JMX bean).

Comment: Hello, I am just trying to create a DB using the Jaybird FAQ example. Follows mu code:
FBManager fbManager  = new FBManager("PURE_JAVA");
String DB_SERVER_URL = "localhost";
int DB_SERVER_PORT = 3050;
String DB_PATH = "c:/database";
String DB_NAME = "test.gdb";
String DB_USER = "sysdba";
String DB_PASSWORD = "masterkey";
fbManager.setServer(DB_SERVER_URL);
fbManager.setPort(DB_SERVER_PORT);
fbManager.start();
fbManager.createDatabase(DB_PATH + "/" + DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
and
import org.firebirdsql.management.FBManager;

resulting in the error I mentioned.

Thanks again.

Comment: Don't put code in a comment, add it in your question, preferably including the imports in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was due to the fact I did not imported the full driver package within my project in  Netbeans. Once I did it , adding the Jaybird...jar file to the libraries everything worked ok.
Thanks for any naswer. Gianluca